# Crazy Cool Categories

Tags: connections-puzzle

<sub>I'm sorry about the title; I lost a bet with the '90s.</sub>

---

Below are five categories. Each category is united by one word in the category; furthermore, each category rule is formed in the same way as the other category.

**Find the word in each category that holds the category together.**

1. > pilgrim, car, antirealist, brotherhood, thornbush
2. > predator, abluent, dastard, flag, oilcloth
3. > plush, math, terminus, basinet, splotch
4. > music, nanotech, barbell, steppe, country
5. > piranha, woman, peruse, formality, map

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In each category,

> one word is an object; the others each hide a word associated with that object.

1:

> pilg**rim**, **[car]**, an**tire**alist, brother**hood**, t**horn**bush

2:

> p**red**ator, a**blue**nt, da**star**d, **[flag]**, oil**cloth**

3:

> **plus**h, **[math]**, ter**minus**, ba**sin**et, s**plot**ch

4:

> **[music]**, na**note**ch, **bar**bell, **step**pe, **count**ry

5:

> p**iran**ha, w**oman**, **peru**se, for**mali**ty, **[map]**

Comment: Well done! FWIW, I intended to use the "e" in "basinet"